# Query Drupal 8 content types with expression

Tags: drupal-8, drupal-database

In short, I need to do an entity query while running an expression. I can't find any way to accomplish this. I'm assuming there should be two ways.

1. An entity query with an expression - When I try this I can't get any expressions to work
2. a raw DB query, but I'm not familiar with how to join all the fields related to the content type of nodes I need.

Here is a shorthand example of what I need to accomplish

```
X = content type
y = field on x content type
z = field on x content type
My expression below is just an example, but need to run this in the database query

- Select y and z from x
- if x > y return node id
```

Any help would be great. This is going to run on a very large dataset, trying to find the fastest way to do the query in the database.

Comment: [This page](https://www.drupaleasy.com/blogs/ultimike/2020/07/entityquery-examples-everybody) may help

Comment: Do you mean `if z > y return node id`?

Answer (score 0):

Comparing two fields is not possible using the entity query.

To do this, you may need to use the more low level [Dynamic Queries](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/database-api/dynamic-queries) and its [where](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Database%21Query%21SelectExtender.php/function/SelectExtender%3A%3Awhere/8.6.x) method:

```php
$query = \Drupal::database()->select('node_field_data', 'n');
$query->condition('n.type', 'x');                               // to get content type x
$query->innerJoin('node__field_y', 'y', 'y.entity_id = n.nid'); // join with field y
$query->innerJoin('node__field_z', 'z', 'z.entity_id = n.nid'); // join with field z
$query->where('z.field_z_value > y.field_y_value');             // your condition
$query->addField('n', 'nid');                                   // get node id in result
$results = $query->execute()->fetchAllKeyed(0, 0);
```